# jquery ui tabs in wordpress homepage

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, tabs

I was wondering if there was a way to display or have multiple pages in tabs on wordpress homepage as shown on these sites:

http://www.mybiolumix.com/

http://www.1up.com/

I will prefer to do this without plugins

I really need to this urgently.

Many thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

What you need are these:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Follow the examples in the documentation, they're pretty easy to set up.